# pygame switching between menu causes crash: "video system not initializated"

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, crash

I'm new to pygame, and I'm trying to make a menu for my game. For now, I want two different screens, one that will show in the menu and other that will show in the "custom" part of the game. I tried to create a main loop and two inner loops that only run when they are supposed to.

For now, the transition between menu and custom is done thought pressing key "d". The transition menu to custom is done perfectly, but the transition custom to menu is crashing the game

This is the main loop:

```
while running:
    while menu:
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                running = 0
                menu = 0
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d):
                custom = 1
                menu = 0
    while custom:
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(bgCustom, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                running = 0
                custom = 0
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d):
                custom = 0
                menu = 1
    pygame.quit()
```

The error I'm getting when I'm in "while custom" and press "d" to go back to the menu is "pygame.error: video system not initializated". The logic seems the same for both so I'm bewildered. Also, I have already initializated pygame, using pygame.init(), so that is not the problem here. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: As Rabbid76 stated, in his answer, the error was my identation in "pygame.quit()". It stopped my video system. The only problem was the last line. Correct loop below:

```
while running:
    while menu:
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                running = 0
                menu = 0
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d):
                custom = 1
                menu = 0
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_1):
                playMusic(1)
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_2):
                playMusic(2)
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_0):
                playMusic(0)
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_3):
                playMusic(3)

    while custom:
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.blit(bgCustom, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                running = 0
                custom = 0
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d):
                custom = 0
                menu = 1
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The last statement in the `while` loop is `pygame.quit()`. [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html) uninitialize all pygame modules.
Invoke `pygame.quit()` after the loop. rather than in the loop:

```py
while running:
    while menu:
        # [...]

    while custom:
        # [...]

#<--| INDENTATION
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: oh, I see! It unintialize pygame, so the video system did not initializated and crashed. Thanks! Really apreciated the concise and clean answer!